# GeoServer doesnt generate tiles for EPSG:3857 grid

Tags: geoserver, geojson, web-mercator

I failing to generate .geojson tiles with GeoServer for grid with EPSG:3857 projection.

Note that it successfully generate .png tiles with the same config, and also .geojson generation works for other projections like EPSG:4326.

[image]

Logs: https://easyupload.io/oo573g

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Officially GeoJSON supports only EPSG:4326 but unofficially it is possible to use also other crs. I do not know if Geoserver wants to be strict with GeoJSON.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Error messages and code should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. It is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google. Please take the [tour] to see how this site works.

Comment: @user30184, RFC GeoJSON isn't EPSG:4326, it's CRS:84

Comment: Right, exactly "The coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates is a  geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic System 1984 (WGS 84) [WGS84] datum, with longitude and latitude units of decimal degrees.  This is equivalent to the coordinate reference system identified by the Open Geospatial consortium (OGC) URN urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84." Can be converted from EPSG:4326 by writing longitudes before latitudes.

Comment: @IanTurton I couldn't find anything specific in the logs. https://easyupload.io/oo573g